# 子ダイアログ内のCCheckListBoxコントロール内に追加したチェックボックスに✔を入れる方法が分からない

Tags: mfc

MFCで子ダイアログ内のCCheckListBoxコントロール内に追加したチェックボックスに✔を入れる方法が分からず問題で困っています。

以下は参考gifです。
子ダイアログ上のチェックボックスに✔を入れたいのですが、入れられません。
また、✔を入れられたら、✔を外せるようにしたいです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上記の処理作成のために、私が作ったソースは以下です。
ToDoDlg.h(子ダイアログのクラスヘッダー)

```cpp
#pragma once


// ToDoDlg ダイアログ

class ToDoDlg : public CDialogEx
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(ToDoDlg)

public:
    ToDoDlg(CWnd* pParent = nullptr);   // 標準コンストラクター
    virtual ~ToDoDlg();

// ダイアログ データ
#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
    enum { IDD = IDD_TODO_DIALOG };
#endif

protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV サポート


// 実装
protected:
    HICON m_hIcon;
    // 生成された、メッセージ割り当て関数
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

private:
    /*privateメンバ変数*/
    // To Do項目チェックボックスコントロールリスト変数
    CCheckListBox m_check_list_box;
    // To Do項目表示文字列入力変数
    CString m_add_edit;

    /*privateメンバ関数*/
    afx_msg void OnEnKillfocusCaptionEdit();
public:
    afx_msg void OnIdok();

};
```

ToDoDlg.cpp(子ダイアログのクラス実装部分)

```cpp
// ToDoDlg.cpp : 実装ファイル
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "LearningPokect.h"
#include "ToDoDlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"

// ToDoDlg ダイアログ

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(ToDoDlg, CDialogEx)

ToDoDlg::ToDoDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=nullptr*/)
    : CDialogEx(IDD_TODO_DIALOG, pParent)
    , m_add_edit(_T(""))
{
}

ToDoDlg::~ToDoDlg()
{
}

void ToDoDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_ITEM_ADD_EDIT, m_add_edit);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_TO_DO_LIST, m_check_list_box);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(ToDoDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_EN_KILLFOCUS(IDC_ITEM_ADD_EDIT, &ToDoDlg::OnEnKillfocusCaptionEdit)
    ON_COMMAND(IDOK, &ToDoDlg::OnIdok)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL ToDoDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // "バージョン情報..." メニューをシステム メニューに追加します。

    // IDM_ABOUTBOX は、システム コマンドの範囲内になければなりません。
    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != nullptr)
    {
        BOOL bNameValid;
        CString strAboutMenu;
        bNameValid = strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        ASSERT(bNameValid);
        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
        }
    }

    // このダイアログのアイコンを設定します。アプリケーションのメイン ウィンドウがダイアログでない場合、
    //  Framework は、この設定を自動的に行います。
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // 大きいアイコンの設定
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // 小さいアイコンの設定

    // TODO: 初期化をここに追加します。

    // MFCのチェックリストコントロールが二重に表示されるバグを直すコード
    // 参考：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57951333/cchecklistbox-items-get-overlapped-on-selection-if-app-build-using-visual-studi
    m_check_list_box.SetFont(GetFont());

    // Set the CheckStyle to BS_3STATE, so that check state notifications can be received
    m_check_list_box.SetCheckStyle(BS_3STATE);

    return TRUE;  // フォーカスをコントロールに設定した場合を除き、TRUE を返します。
}

// ToDoDlg メッセージ ハンドラー


void ToDoDlg::OnEnKillfocusCaptionEdit()
{
    // TODO: ここにコントロール通知ハンドラー コードを追加します。
    /*エディットコントロールから入力文字を取得し、
    チェックボックスリストコントロールの表示文字に設定する*/

    // エディットコントロールの値変数にエディットコントロールで
    // 入力された文字列を代入する
    UpdateData(TRUE);

    /*取得した文字列をチェックボックスリストコントロールに設定する
     ダイアログウィンドウを最初に表示する時に
     ToDoDlg::OnEnKillfocusCaptionEdit()が呼ばれた際
     チェックボックスリストコントロールに空文字の項目が作成されないように
     以下の条件文を作成した*/
     // エディットコントロールの値変数が空でない場合
    if (!m_add_edit.IsEmpty())
    {
        // チェックボックスリストコントロールに
        // エディットコントロールの値変数に格納されている
        // 文字列を追加する
        m_check_list_box.AddString(m_add_edit);

        // チェックボックスリストコントロールに
        // エディットコントロールの値変数に格納し終えたので、
        // エディットコントロールの値変数に入力されている文字列を削除する
        m_add_edit = _T("");
        UpdateData(FALSE);


    }

    /* 入力した文字列はエディットコントロールから削除する */
}

/*Enter押下時のイベントハンドラ*/
void ToDoDlg::OnIdok()
{
    // TODO: ここにコマンド ハンドラー コードを追加します。
    // OnEnKillfocusCaptionEditイベントハンドラ内の
    // 必要な処理を関数化して、ここにも貼り付ける
    // 理由：Enterを押したときにOnEnKillfocusCaptionEditと
    // 同様の処理をするため。
}
```

試してみたことは以下です。
・MFCダイアログベースプロジェクトを新規作成して、最初に自動作成されるダイアログにCCheckListBoxコントロールを作成して、✔を入れる処理を作った。
試した理由：
子ダイアログでないダイアログなら✔を入れる処理を書かなくても✔を入れたり外したりする処理が作れるか確認するため。
結果：
チェックボックスに✔を入れたり外したりできた。

ただ、なぜ本問題が起きている子ダイアログにCCheckListBoxコントロールを作成すると、チェックボックスに✔を入れたり、外したりできないかが分かりませんでした。

なので、ソースを手動で書けばよいと思い、SetCheck関数を使って、✔を入れたり外したりする処理を作ろうと思いましたが、CCheckListBoxのプロパティにあるどのイベントを使えばよいか分かりませんでした。

解決策を教えて頂けるとありがたいです。どうかよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 親ダイアログで試したという内容の記述が矛盾しているか、説明が不足している感じです。もう少し整理して詳しい説明を書いてみてください。そしてそれを子ダイアログ上にどう移植したか？(したいか？)についても追記してみてください。あとKillFocusイベントを使うのは止めた方が良いのでは？

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
記述が矛盾していました。すみません。
親ダイアログで試したのではなく、正しくはMFCダイアログベースの新規プロジェクトで最初に自動作成されたダイアログで試しました。

子ダイアログにどう移植したいかは、そもそも親ダイアログ上で試していなので、記載しませんでした。
その代わりに、私の文章が分かりにくいと思い、問題の参考gifと説明文を追記してもう少し分かりやすいようにしました。

KillFocusのご指摘ありがとうございます。ですが、今MFCの勉強をしている理由が、会社の業務をできるようにするためで、会社でKillFocusを使っている処理があり、その理解をしたいので、使っております。

Comment: `KillFocus`の処理を理解したいというのと、今回やりたいことは独立した別々のことだと思います。いったん分けて考えた方が良いでしょう。その上で、いったん`KillFocus`での処理は止めて(すべてコメントアウトして)、代わりにボタンコントロールを追加して、そのOnBnClicked処理で(KillFocus処理で行っていた)CheckListBoxへの項目追加を行ってみてください。それから`ToDoDlg`の`OnInitDialog`の処理も、最後の`return TRUE;`以外をすべてコメントアウトしてみてください。[CTabCtrlにCDialogを埋め込む(VC++)](https://www.kazetest.com/vcmemo/dlgintab/dlgintab.htm)を基に改造した処理では、そんな感じで動作しています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。お陰様でOnInitDialg内の
m_check_list_box.SetCheckStyle(BS_3STATE);
をコメントアウトアウトしたら、期待通り動作しました。

ちなみに上記の対応をした状態で、CheckListBoxへの項目追加をボタンコントロールのOnBnClickedに作成してもkillFocusに作成してもチェックボックスに✔を入れたり外したりできました。

最後に、もしもお答え頂ければでありがたいです。なぜ色んな機能の呼び出しにkillFocusを使い回すことは予期せぬ問題を呼び込むのでしょうか？

killFocusはフォーカスがそのコントロールにある状態から、他のコントロールにフォーカスが移ったときに呼ばれるという理解ですが、どのような場合に予期せぬ問題が起きるのかが想像できませんでした（予期せぬ問題なので予期できないのかもしれませんが）。

ただ、MSDNを見たら、killfocusの備考に、「このメッセージの処理中は、ウィンドウを表示またはアクティブ化する関数呼び出しを行わないでください。これにより、スレッドが制御を委譲し、アプリケーションがメッセージへの応答を停止する可能性があります。」

とありますが、このような問題が起きる可能性があるということでしょうか？

Comment: 大変申し訳ございません。本問題は解決したと思いましたが、チェックリストボックスに追加した最初のチェックボックスのみ✔を入れた後に、チェックが外せないという問題が残っていました。現在この問題の解決に取り組んでいます。

Comment: MSDNのそれはKillFocus処理自身に対する注意ですね。それ以前に貴方が思っている以外のタイミングでもKillFocusが発生するからです。以前の質問のように同一プログラム内でも入力中にメッセージダイアログを表示するとか、1つのプログラム内では想定も制御も出来ない別プログラムのウインドウやタスクバー等をクリックすることでも発生します。それから、「...チェックが外せない...」に関しては`...SetCheckStyle(BS_3STATE);`のように何か余計な処理が残っているのでは？ 私の回答のように紹介記事にCheckListBoxやボタンとその処理を追加した程度ならば、その現象は発生していませんし。

Comment: KillFocusについてさらに詳しく教えて頂き本当にありがとうございました。

「...チェックが外せない...」もお陰様で問題を解決しました。原因はおっしゃる通り余計な処理が入っており、ON_CLBN_CHKCHANGEのメッセージ処理のイベントハンドラでm_check_list_box.SetCheck(0, TRUE);を書いており、m_check_list_box内のチェックボックスの✔状態が変更されると、一番最初に追加したチェックボックスの✔が入るように設定していたためでした。

今後はテストで試しに追加した処理の消し忘れに注意します。気づかせて頂きありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CTabCtrlにCDialogを埋め込む(VC++)](https://www.kazetest.com/vcmemo/dlgintab/dlgintab.htm)を以下のように改造して特に問題無く動作しています。
Visual Studio Community 2019でプロジェクトをアップグレードして改造

`TabDlg.rc`の主な変更部分

```
IDD_TABDLG_DIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 139, 170
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
EXSTYLE WS_EX_APPWINDOW
CAPTION "TabDlg"
FONT 9, "MS UI Gothic", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    CONTROL         "",IDC_TAB1,"SysTabControl32",0x0,7,7,125,140
    PUSHBUTTON      "Button1",IDC_BUTTON1,7,148,35,15
END

IDD_DIALOG1 DIALOGEX 0, 0, 124, 120
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_CHILD | WS_SYSMENU
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    LTEXT           "データ１",IDC_STATIC,7,7,30,9
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT1,7,23,82,15,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    PUSHBUTTON      "Add",IDC_BUTTON1,90,23,27,15
    LISTBOX         IDC_LIST1,7,40,110,73,LBS_SORT | LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED | LBS_HASSTRINGS | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
END
```

`Dlg1.h`

```
#pragma once
// CDlg1 dialog
class CDlg1 : public CDialog
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CDlg1)
public:
    CDlg1(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
    virtual ~CDlg1();
// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_DIALOG1 };
protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    CString m_strEdit1;
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedButton1();
    CCheckListBox m_check_list_box;
};
```

`Dlg1.cpp`

```
// Dlg1.cpp : implementation file
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TabDlg.h"
#include "Dlg1.h"
// CDlg1 dialog
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CDlg1, CDialog)
CDlg1::CDlg1(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CDlg1::IDD, pParent)
    , m_strEdit1(_T(""))
{
}
CDlg1::~CDlg1()
{
}
void CDlg1::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_strEdit1);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST1, m_check_list_box);
}
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CDlg1, CDialog)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, &CDlg1::OnBnClickedButton1)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
// CDlg1 message handlers
void CDlg1::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    UpdateData(TRUE);
    if (!m_strEdit1.IsEmpty())
    {
        m_check_list_box.AddString(m_strEdit1);
        m_strEdit1 = _T("");
        UpdateData(FALSE);
    }
}
```

表示結果

[image: 子ダイアログのCheckListBox]